# Can this unpooling operation be rewritten so that Keras can calculate the derivative?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, keras

I'm trying to create an unpooling layer using Keras with the TensorFlow backend. The unpooling operation that I am trying to implement is described in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1311.2901v3.pdf). This is the same unpooling operation that SegNet uses.

> Unpooling: In the convnet, the max pooling operation
>   is non-invertible, however we can obtain an approximate
>   inverse by recording the locations of the
>   maxima within each pooling region in a set of switch
>   variables. In the deconvnet, the unpooling operation
>   uses these switches to place the reconstructions from
>   the layer above into appropriate locations, preserving
>   the structure of the stimulus.

Most of my code is an adaptation of [this implementation](https://gist.github.com/PavlosMelissinos/6ddb1ba86f51214477a76ce670d18c97) from an older version of Keras.

So far I have written a custom layer and it is performing the unpooling operation correctly. The problem I am running into is when Keras tries to compute the gradient during the back-prop stage, I get the error:

```py
raise ValueError('An operation has `None` for gradient. '
ValueError: An operation has `None` for gradient. Please make sure that all of your ops have a gradient defined (i.e. are differentiable). Common ops without gradient: K.argmax, K.round, K.eval.
```

As far as I understand, this error is being caused because I must be using an operation that Keras doesn't know the derivative for.

Here is my code:

```py
from keras import backend as K
from keras.engine.topology import Layer
from keras.layers import UpSampling2D
import numpy as np
import operator

class MyUnpooler(Layer):

    # Initialisations
    def __init__(self, pool_layer, pool_input, size=(2,2), **kwargs):
        self.pool_layer = pool_layer
        self.pool_input = pool_input
        self.size = size
        super(MyUnpooler, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    # This method would be used to create weights
    # I don't have any trainable weights but this must be implemented
    def build(self, input_shape):
        super(MyUnpooler, self).build(input_shape)

    # This method is for the layers' logic
    # x is always input to the layer
    def call(self, x):
        # Zeros for later
        zeros = K.zeros_like(self.pool_input)

        # Mask template
        upsampled = UpSampling2D(size=self.size)(self.pool_layer)
        upsampled_shape = upsampled.get_shape().as_list()[1:]
        input_shape = self.pool_input.get_shape().as_list()[1:]

        size_diff = map(operator.sub, input_shape, upsampled_shape)
        unfiltered_mask = K.spatial_2d_padding(upsampled, padding=((0,size_diff[1]),(0,size_diff[2])))

        # Create the mask
        self.mask = K.tf.equal(self.pool_input, unfiltered_mask)
        assert self.mask.get_shape().as_list() == self.pool_input.get_shape().as_list()

        self.unpooled = K.tf.where(self.mask, self.pool_input, zeros)
        return K.tf.to_float(self.unpooled)

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        # input_shape is not actually the input shape we need...
        # We need to be able to UpSample the layer to calculate the dimensions
        upsampled = UpSampling2D(size=self.size)(self.pool_layer)
        upsampled_shape = upsampled.get_shape().as_list()[1:]
        inp_shape = self.pool_input.get_shape().as_list()[1:]

        size_diff = map(operator.sub, inp_shape, upsampled_shape)
        unf_mask = K.spatial_2d_padding(upsampled, padding=((0,size_diff[1]),(0,size_diff[2])))

        return tuple(unf_mask.get_shape().as_list())
```

If there is a better way of doing the unpooling operation I am also open to completely disregarding my attempt so far.

Comment: Can you add some more details what your layer is supposed to do? So, which algorithm/approach does it implement.

Comment: @FlashTek Sure, I have added some more information to the top of the post.